# For loops string Assignment

Tags: c

How does one use a for loop to print out a string the user enters with a "*" between each letter in C?

Any guidance on this problem would greatly be appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char YourVariable[20];
    int i;

    printf("Please enter a name: ", YourVariable);

    for( i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
        scanf ("%c" , &YourVariable[i]);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I know that this is simply the beginning, but I do not know how to implement a code that can put a "*" between every character that a user will input.

An​ example of how the program should function:

Input: Flower

Output: F * l * o * w * e * r

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Show us some code and what you're having trouble understanding

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?  Have you made an attempt?  If so, please post it along with *specific* questions about what might be going wrong.

Comment: I have attempted at it:

#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

char YourVariable[20];
int i;

printf("Please enter a name: ", YourVariable);

for( i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
  scanf ("%c" , &YourVariable[i]) ;
}

return 0; 
}

However, this one does not print out the "*" between each character. I'm still trying to figure this out since I am a beginner.

Comment: @ARTINAMADANI Edit your question and add the code to the question.  Also, this code makes no attempt to output anything.  You need to try that as well and let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: @ARTINAMADANI Did you write this yourself, or did your professor provide this for you to fill in the blanks?

Comment: I wrote it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a for loop to go over each character in the user entered string, print that character, and then print the '*'.  Psuedo code might look something like:

```
Read input string from user into array
for each character in the array
    print character
    print '*'
```

Comment: Unless you're going for super-user, I think you meant "pseudo" code.

Comment: This is the code I have so far, but I don't think I understand what you mean. I don't know how to implement what you are saying in the form of code.

#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){

char YourVariable[20];
int i;

printf("Please enter a name: ", YourVariable);

for( i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
  scanf ("%c" , &YourVariable[i]) ;

}

return 0; 
}

Comment: If you could edit your original post with this code then it would be a lot more readable and easier to help.